# Should my program be flawless at release

Tags: open-source, source-code, clean-code, app

I'm building a big, very complex piece of open-source software, and it's killing me trying to make what I have as "clean" as it needs to be.

What I want to know is: If there is an undetected flaw in my program and/or my code cleanliness (is that a word?), can that harm my reputation?

Likewise, is it bad that I've reused code from an already open-source app but have rewritten it my way?

Thanks.

Comment: If some code exists, it has bugs. Well, unless it has formal proof of correctness, but it can have bugs too.

Comment: Don't forget "bugs" in the requirements. Even formal proofs can't help you there.

Comment: Sometimes when a project is sufficiently big or too complicated, it needs multiple eyes to find solutions. This is distinct from the [FOSS "eyeballs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_Law) - you need some highly skilled and dedicated persons to help you, not from some random passerbys or cynics.

Comment: "is it bad that I've reused code from an already open-source app" - not as long as you followed the license terms of that app. You did not read them, otherwise you would not have asked, I guess? So go and read them. Now. No excuses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no such thing as a flawless program, so don't aim for that.

What you should aim for in for a first release is good/thorough documentation, some automated tests, one or more places for people to tell you about any problems they have or features they'd like to see, and a clear/prominent description of what your program library is and *is not* supposed to accomplish. And it should *actually work*, obviously.

Regarding reputation, I would expect people to care more about how you respond to bug reports/feature requests and how your program evolves rather than how pristine it might be at version 1.0. If you have at least the things I mentioned above, you'll be in a good position to respond well to all the input you'll inevitably get.

Reusing code from another app is fine *if the license allowed it* and you follow all the license terms. I would also try to attribute it somewhere even the license doesn't require it; that's just more polite.

Comment: As an extreme example of my point about reputation, Linus Torvalds has the reputation that he does [because of the stuff he says](http://www.attendly.com/linux-founder-linus-torvalds-delivers-a-smackdown-like-no-other/), not because of some imperfection in Linux or git.